# Multiple vector integration in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have a random variable y with density f(y | theta_1, ..., theta_p), and a posterior distribution pi(theta_1, ..., theta_p). I want to get

f(y) = int ... int f(y | theta_1, ..., theta_p) pi(theta_1, ..., theta_p) dtheta_1 ... dtheta_p.

I tried `scipy.integrate.nquad` but it doesn't take vector inputs (need to compute f(y) on entire support) and `scipy.integrate.quad_vec`, but I'm not sure how to use this for integration over multiple variables.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

p = 3  # Number of parameters, in reality much higher.

# integrand(y, *t) = f(y | *t) pi(*t)
def integrand(y, *t):
    # Using normal as example, real distribution more complicated.
    return np.exp(sum(-(y - ti)**2 for ti in t))

def f(y):
    res = scipy.integrate.nquad(
        lambda *t: integrand(y, *t),
        [[-np.inf, np.inf]] * p
    )

    return res[0]
```

This works for single value y, but not for vector input.
It also takes a very long time.

Comment: High-dimensional integrals are often computed via Monte Carlo methods, although you could take a look at your density function and see if a symbolic result is possible.